# Map goes to 100% and then down to 0%?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new at MR, but this doesn't seem like it should be able to happen. This is output:

```
 11/12/07 13:24:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201112071322_0001
 11/12/07 13:24:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
 11/12/07 13:24:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
 11/12/07 13:41:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 16%
 11/12/07 13:42:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
 11/12/07 13:59:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
 11/12/07 14:00:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
 11/12/07 14:00:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Notice the times. It also just sits there, and does not complete, or error. I would imagine the error would be in the reducer, so I included it; if other code is suspect, I'll post it, just ask.

Code: http://pastebin.com/uuL1Cgx4

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into the logs of the reducer?

Comment: Can you provide job tracker log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meet similar problems several days ago. My mapper will down to 0% after reach 100%.

Finally I found that data types definition of map output and reduce input is different. So that copy/shuffle/merge  data flow option between map and reduce will not work, even though hadoop JobTracker retry to do it.

Hope it will be useful for you.